# A problem on relating the derivative of two associated polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, polynomials, complex-numbers

If $P(z)=z-z_1$ and $Q(z)=z-(1/z_1)$ where $0<|z_1|<1,$ then
$|z_1||P'(z)|=|z_1|<1=|Q'(z)|$ on $|z|=1.$
I am thinking of extending this property to polynomial of degree 2.
If $P(z)=(z-z_1)(z-z_2)$ and $Q(z)=(z-(1/z_1))(z-(1/z_2)),$ where $0<|z_1|<1, 0<|z_1|\leq |z_2|<1,$  then I am trying to prove or disprove the following
$|z_1|^2 \max_{|z|=1}|P'(z)| \leq\max_{|z|=1}|Q'(z)|.$
Kind request to share any thoughts on this claim.

Comment: Does $|z_2|<1$?

Comment: You need more conditions - take $4/5, 4/3$ for the $2 z's$ and you get $Q$ to have a critical point at $1$ so the inequality fails; by a classic theorem the critical points of a polynomial are in the convex hull of the roots so need to ensure $Q$ has no critical points on the circle somehow

Comment: $1/4, -1/2$ still lead to $Q$ having a critical point at $1$; you need the mean of $\frac{1}{z_1}$,  $\frac{1}{z_2}$ to avoid the unit circle just to ensure $Q$ has no critical point there